# Roots in a limited disc

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

a) Find the roots that satisfy $|z|<1$ in the polynomial $P=z^9-2z^6+z^2-8z-2$.
There is a general method for this?

b) Show that, if $|a|>e$ so $e^z=az^n$ have $n$ toots in the disc $|z|<1$

I know we use the Rouché's theorem, but I didn't get anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw in an answer to part (b) here.  As a fairly direct application of Rouché's, set $f(z) = -e^z$ and $g(z) = az^n$, and consider that along the unit circle $\{z: z = e^{i\theta}\}$, $|f(z)| = |e^{e^{i\theta}}| < e < |g(z)| = |a||e^{in\theta}| = a$.  The function $g(z) = az^n$ has a root at zero of multiplicity $n$, and so $f(z) +g (z) = az^n - e^z$ has $n$ roots inside the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

its simple take $f(z)=-8z $ and  $g(z)=z^9-2z^6+z^2-2$ then |g(z)/f(z)|<1 hence by Rouche thm f(z) and f(z)+g(z) have same number of zeros incide |f(z)|<1. but f(z) have one zero incide 
 |f(z)|<1.hence the required function